# Negative regex matching

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to replace all `*`(that do not have `.` before them) in my string with `.*`.

Expected results -

1. foo*  --> foo.*
2. foo.* --> foo.*

I tried `re.sub("(?!\.)\*", ".*", "foo*")` to replace all such occurrences, but this does not seem to work.

```
>>> re.sub("(?!\.)\*", ".*", "foo.*")
   'foo..*'
```

Any help on what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\.)` to assert what is on the left is not a dot:

`(?<!\.)(\*)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9euuH/1)

For example:

```
test_str = """foo*
foo.*
"""
result = re.sub(r"(?<!\.)(\*)", r".\1", test_str)
print (result)
```

Result

```
foo.*
foo.*
```

Comment: Thanks...I was missing `<` for lookbehind. This works for me

Comment: @Jan I think he was not.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Right you are, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You were using a neg. *lookahead* (`(?!...)`), not a *lookbehind* (`(?<!...)`), see

```
import re

string = """
foo* --> foo.*
foo.* --> foo.*
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?<!\.)\*')

string = rx.sub('.*', string)
print(string)
```

And [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wdKVRp/1/).

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as from @Thefourthbird. Both work for me. Thankyou so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it like this:

```
[^\.]\*
```

Comment: And how would a replacement look like here? You could *capture* it and then use the captured group in the replacement like [**`([^.])\*`**](https://regex101.com/r/wdKVRp/2). Also please note that you do not need to escape the dot in square brackets.

Comment: yea forgot the group ... but it should work with escape too